# How to query MongoDB without switching to the database first

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I connect to MongoDB from the command-line using the `mongo` command, I need to issue a `use <db>` command to switch to the appropriate database before I can run a query, like this:

```
[mongo@mongotest ~] $ mongo localhost:10001
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: localhost:10001/test
> use mydb01
switched to db mydb01
```

Now I can run my query:

```
> db.records.find({"contact.name": "Jack"});
```

Is there a way to consolidate those commands into a single command? For example:

```
> mydb01.records.find({"contact.name": "Jack"});
```

The [MongoDB shell documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) makes it seem like there should be a way, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a database object of another database than the one your are `use`ing right now with [`db.getSiblingDB`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/#db.getSiblingDB).

```
> db.getSiblingDB("mydb01").records.find({"contact.name": "Jack"});
```

You can also store that object in a variable. That way you can easily work with many databases simultaneously.

```
> var mydb01 = db.getSiblingDB("mydb01");
> mydb01.records.find({"contact.name": "Jack"});
```